# PageCotroller error ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views

Tags: flutter, dart, controller, flutter-pageview

I have a class like this :

```
class MyController {
  static PageController globalController = PageController(initialPage: 0);

  void diispose() {
    globalController.dispose();
  }
}
```

I'd like to use this `PageController` in two different locations to modify the`PageView`
however after use `MyController.globalController.jumpToPage(1);` I got this error :

```
ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart':
package:flutter/…/widgets/scroll_controller.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 108 pos 12: '_positions.length == 1'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot use the same PageController for two scroll views, but you can create one for each scroll and one method that jump all scrolls to page, as the example below:

```dart
class MyController {
  static PageController globalControllerOne = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  static PageController globalControllerTwo = PageController(initialPage: 0);

  void jumpToPage(int page) {
    globalControllerOne.jumpToPage(page);
    globalControllerTwo.jumpToPage(page);
  }

  void dispose() {
    globalController.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: In my case, I'd like to control a single ```PageView``` from two different locations using a single ```PageController``` connected to my widget. For example, I'd like to have a button somewhere in my app that changes the BottomNavigationBar items using ```PageController```.